# How to pass data to AppServiceProvider?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm trying to pass the `$product` variable in this controller to multiple view files.

```
function show($lang, $slug)
{
    $product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

    $mightAlsoLike = Product::where('slug', '!=', $slug)->MightAlsoLike()->get();

    return view('shop_show')->with(['product' => $product, 'mightAlsoLike' => $mightAlsoLike]);
}
```

I'm using view composer in `AppServiceProvider` to pass the data to multiple view files but the problem is that the data in the variable needs the `$slug` param. how do I pass that `$slug` param to `AppServiceProvider`?

```
 public function boot()
{
    View::composer(['shop_show', 'partials/menus/right_bar'], function ($view) {
        $site_slug = Route::current()->parameter('slug');

        $product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

        $view->with(['product' => $product]);
    });
}
```

EDIT: the `$site_slug` variable returns null.

SOLVED: I defined my `$slug` param as `{product}` in my routes. changing the `$site_slug` variable to `$site_slug = Route::current()->parameter('product');` fixed the issue.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you're doing with `$site_slug` in the View Composer?

Comment: the $site_slug variable returns null.

Comment: This is an assumption, but often a product detail page URL looks as follows, `site.com/product/product-slug`. So what you could do is get the segments `$segments =  request()->segments();`. Then, you know the last segment will be the slug, so `$site_slug = end($segments);`. This only applies if your URL follows the same structure as I noted above

Comment: set your own solution as an answer and mark it as best answer ^_^

Comment: Thanks, your solution also worked. it returns an array of all the segments and the last one as you said is the slug. my issue was solved pretty easily though, I just had to rename the parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I defined my `$slug` param as `{product}` in my routes. changing the `$site_slug` variable to `$site_slug = Route::current()->parameter('product');` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
public function boot()
{
   
    view()->share('categoryList', $categoriesList);
    view()->share('packageList', $packageList);
    view()->share('testList', $testList);
    view()->share('testList1', $testList1);

}
```